# How fix broken KDE?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde

After I updated my Nvidia-319 to Nvidia-331 KDE got broken . taskbar became black and minimize and maximize doesn't work . Even Konsole doesn't work . I reinstalled Nvidia but nothin has changed . How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal from the Mint Menu and start with the commands:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install gtkorphan
```

The && is used to run the second command if the first command runs successfully.

Continue by running:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

This is used to double-check that you have all the updates.

To clear out the broken packages use the command:

```
sudo aptitude -f
```

or try to direct fix

```
inxi -Sr
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken --simulate mint-meta-kde
```

Comment: For this, you will have to go to TTY1 (CTRL+ALT+F1) and log in through there to access the terminal. Also, use `apt-get` in place of `aptitude`, assuming you are running Ubuntu or Kubuntu.

Comment: then try to direct fix, like                  inxi -Sr
          sudo apt-get install --fix-broken                 
          sudo apt-get install --fix-broken --simulate mint-meta-kde